# Meaning of phrase そこそこ上手く、そこそこ下手

Tags: meaning

I'm a bit confused about the part in bold in the following passage. I can't understand what exactly is the speaker talking about with 上手く and 下手? Is he talking about how the one could be 'so-so good in one subject, and equally bad at some other'?

> ジュウは今まで学校の授業を一元的に見ていた部分があり、どの教師も同じようなものだと思っていた。**そこそこ上手く、そこそこ下手**。授業なんてそんなものだろう、と高をくくっていたのだが、その考えを改めることになった。堕花雨の教え方は、妙に上手いのだ。いつものように[抑揚]{よくよう}のない口調なのだが、それが何故か心地よく、頭にすんなりと入っていく。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The speaker is talking about teachers at school, and that sentence means no teacher is particularly good or bad at teaching something. It's not an idiomatic phrase, but you can understand it as "moderately good and bad at the same time," "not remarkable at all."